# CSS override, first loaded style sheet taking precedent

Tags: html, css, gruntjs

I have a very strange issue I cannot quite figure out with my css style sheets. I have 2 stylesheets, one is from a cdn, one is minified then injected onto my index.html (locally) on my local dev server right now. So just for a quick reference, in my header I have something like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCDNStyleSheet.css">
<!-- injector:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/localMinifiedStyles.css?1474574347809">
<!-- endinjector -->
```

So that is just using a grunt task with `grunt-cssmin` and `grunt-injector` to put that stylesheet with it's own hash on.

Now what's weird is, even though the `myCDNStyleSheet` is loaded first, some styles from it are taking precent over styles in the `localMinifiedStyles`, and so currently, I've had to put some `!important` on the styles in 'localMinifiedStyles', which is very strange to me.

So to be super clear, what I mean is :

`myCDNStyleSheet.css` has :

```
  .styleMe {
      margin-left: 5px
  }
```

and `localMinifiedStyles.css` has :

```
 .styleThis {
     margin-left: 12px
 }
```

And the rendered html looking like :

```
 <div class="styleMe styleThis">
```

is using the `margin-left: 5px` instead of the 12. I can see them both in the inspector.

Swapping their load order does not fix this, in fact it breaks it further because there are some styles in `localMinifiedStyles` that are taking priority correctly.

Even when inspecting the styles in chrome devtools, I see the `localMinifiedStyles` is below the style that is taking precent. I can't figure out the cause of this, is it possible the grunt injection does something I am not aware of? My assumption thus far in working with css is the last loaded stylesheet takes priority, and I missing something here?

Comment: Without seeing the dev tools, it's difficult to do testing. I'm sure I'm asking something you have already tried, but have you tried checking for css later in the style sheet, that you may not know about?

Comment: Did you try to make your second style more precise? For example, instead of just .styleThis => div.styleThis?

Comment: Can you link to a site that does this? I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/r3cq5xgt/) that simulates this, but I can't get it to behave the way you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure what caused the behavior you describe (If you have the exact same "priority" of css rule - the latter will win), however a simple way to fix your problem is to duplicate the class in your css definition. If you want the `styleThis` class to take over you can use:

```
.styleThis.styleThis {
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

It's kind of a hack, but it works in up to date versions of chrome, firefox and ie.

```css
.green.green {
  color: green;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red green">
  This text's color should have been red because the red rule is latter in the CSS, however it will be green due to the <code>.green.green</code> in the css rules.
</div>
```

Comment: It's still confusing to me why this is not working, however this does fix the problem currently. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website? It can really help identify the problem...